# Is there a way to test a jar file of my project with junit test cases using CLI(command line interface)?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, javac

I am trying to create a project that helps my eclipse project which is exported as jar file to get junit test performed and provide me the result so for that is there any way to test a jar file of project to test with junit using CLI

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely it is possible. Usually you will want to build a "test" target into your built system so it is able to compile the project first if needed.

If you are using ANT, you will want to use the [Ant JUnit task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) and make sure to pass all the needed dependencies to the `<classpath>` element.

```
<junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${build.tests}"/>
        <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
    </classpath>

    <formatter type="plain"/>

    <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${reports.tests}">
        <fileset dir="${src.tests}">
            <include name="**/*Test*.java"/>
            <exclude name="**/AllTests.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </batchtest>
</junit>
```

If you are using Maven, the [Surefire plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) should be running tests automatically when building the project, or when running `maven test`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the JUnit jar: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Download-and-Install

Then execute the following command:

```
java -cp /path/to/my.jar:/path/to/junit.jar junit.textui.TestRunner com.mypackage.MyClassWithUnitTests
```

If you have windows:

```
java -cp /path/to/my.jar;/path/to/junit.jar junit.textui.TestRunner com.mypackage.MyClassWithUnitTests
```